# Why is the probability that two independently sampled values have the same value is zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In a book about machine learning, it reads,

> Generally, the probability that $x$ generated independently by a continuous probability distribution $p(x)$ have the same value is zero. Otherwise, $\int p(x)dx = \infty$.

Why is it impossible that the same value is sampled more than once?

Comment: Because for continuous distributions, the probability of a point is... zero. Now, in the machine world, one does not really have the assumed "infinite precision", so one could see the same machine precision value generated ...

Comment: @HammyTheGreek Thank you for answering. How do you explain " Otherwise, $\int p(x)dx = \infty$"?

Comment: In simplistic terms w/ abuse of terminology, if points (infinitesimal interval of integration) have non-zero mass, integration over all points (remember, continuous, so there's an "infinite" number of these over the integration range) means an infinite result...

Comment: @HammyTheGreek What if only several points have non-zero mass?

Comment: Remember, for continuous, it's a *density*, not mass. And a probability on a continuous distribution is the integration of that density over some region. But a point has no size - it's size/length is zero. Integration over zero size region is zero. Again, a bit of terminology abuse, and there are things like the Dirac Delta that have all density at one point...

Comment: @HammyTheGreek Can I argue as follows? $P(X=a) = \lim_{\delta\rightarrow +0}P(a-\delta\le X\le a+\delta) = \lim_{\delta\rightarrow +0}p(a)\cdot 2\delta$ = 0. If the limit does not converge to  zero, it means that P(a) = \infty. Therefore, $\int p(x)dx = \infty$